# round image in react native without zoom effect

Tags: react-native

I have the following code :

```
<Image
  style={styles.avatar}
  source={{
  uri: `${BASE_URL}/avatars/${userAvatar}`,
        }}
 resizeMode="cover"
 />
```

and for styling :

```
 avatar: {
    width: 70,
    height: 70,
    borderRadius: 50,
    marginRight: "5%",
  },
```

That code works and displays the image in a circle shape.

The problem is that the image is "zoomed" more or less depending on the difference concerning is  native height and width.

For instance, if I use an image like this one :

https://www.artmajeur.com/medias/hd/a/n/anib/artwork/12741944_humboldt-pinguin-1.jpg

I can't see the head of the pinguin.

If I use the resizeMode="contain" instead of cover, I am not able to get a circle shape.
Plus, I have read that android required the "cover" value.

How can I do to see the whole image (more or less) in a circle shape ?

Comment: can you share an expo snack for the same? will check there

Comment: @GauravRoy https://snack.expo.dev/@myrmelo/brave-popcorn

Comment: hey @Myrmelo , see you can never focus only the face part. if the area where face is keeps on changing, like in penguin its at top, what if lion ? if the face is at center, then it cant be dynamic

Comment: so which part of image do you want to focus

Answer (score 0):

If you want the maintain the dimensions of `avatar` and see the whole image as well, then you could use `resizeMode="stretch"`.

```js
<Image
  style={styles.avatar}
  source={{
  uri: `${BASE_URL}/avatars/${userAvatar}`,
        }}
 resizeMode="stretch"
 />
```

[image]

Depending on the image, this might not look appealing. However, unless you know exactly what images you need to display, there is no way to know which parts of the images you want to zoom in. This is the reason why most applications that allow for example an avatar image require the user to select the section of the image if the aspect ration does not match.

Notice, that the image container still has the circular shape if using a different resizeMode. However, the image itself will not have this shape. We can test this by setting a background color.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for all your answers.

So I need to figure out how I can let the user focus the part he wants